# How to remove leftover packages from unused layers

Tags: spacemacs, package

An easy example is adding `themes-megapack` to `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` in `.spacemacs`, then running `SPC f e R`, and then observing all the added `*-theme` packages in your `package-selected-packages` list.

After commenting `themes-megapack` out of your `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` list, then doing `SPC f e R` and even `SPC q r`, all the `*-theme` packages remain, and executing `package-autoremove` reports "Nothing to autoremove".

How to I clean up all these orphaned packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not touch the variable `dotspacemacs-install-packages` i.e. its value is still `'used-only`, then the packages do get removed (i.e. 'physically' from the elpa directory). However, the variable `package-selected-packages` does not get 'updated' so that it still also shows the uninstalled packages. I guess this could be considered a bug, so you could report it as an issue.

I have only very quickly had a look, but at first glance it looks like doing `M-: (package--save-selected-packages (package--find-non-dependencies))` sets the variable to the 'correct' value again (I could be wrong, but I certainly don't expect it to do any harm, as package management is fully 'controlled' from the dotfile).

Comment: Awesome, I'll file an issue!

Comment: I guess it could help if you refer to this answer. I must say, that I think this really seems a non-critical bug to me, and I guess maintainers will focus on fixing more urgent bugs. But anyway, good to have an issue for it (so it is documented)... it will be very much appreciated...